# Why is this JavaScript code not pulling the aria-label innerText in Google Tag Manager?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to pull the button text from lightboxes set up on my website. It already triggers an event when the button is clicked, but I want to pull the text too.

I came up with the code below through research, but it returns an empty value (not undefined). I don't know much about JavaScript, so I'm sorry if there's something very obvious. I'm learning while doing it. But what am I missing here?

*Edit: I think additional information is needed.

- These are Digioh lightboxes and GTM is installed through an integration. They push the event to the dataLayer, but I want to add more information.

Google Tag Manager Custom JavaScript Variable:

```
function() {
  var el = document.querySelectorAll('[aria-label="Close Modal"]')[0].innerText;
  return el;
}
```

This is the code of one of the lightboxes I'd like to

```
<div id="button5_wrapper">
  <button id="button5" class="button5" aria-label="Close Modal">I'm not interested</button>
</div>
<div id="button6_wrapper">
  <button id="button6" class="button6" aria-label="Close Modal">I don't qualify</button>
</div>
```

Comment: If you have a click event listener you can get the text of the button that was clicked via `e.target.innerText` or `this.innerText` depending on how your event listener is set up.

Comment: Also, the code you shared seems to be working fine when I tried it. Where/when are you calling that function? Maybe the button has no text at the time you called that function.

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/0xvy7pzt/).  Can you update this to a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @James I don't have an event listener because the event is being pushed through an integration with the platform, but would I be able to use something like that to pull the button text with this event?

Comment: You might be able to use a more specific css selector with your current function.  If, say, the button that was pressed gets css class "pressed" you could use `'.pressed[aria-label="Close Modal"]'`  Or if it gets an "aria-pressed=true" attribute you could use `[aria-label="Close Modal"][aria-pressed="true"]`  You'll need to check the app and see what changes with the button elements when they are pressed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're having is that the `innerText` property does not return the `aria-label` attribute. It returns the textual content within the element. You should use `getAttribute()` method to get the attribute value of an element.

In your case, if you want to return the text inside the button (i.e., "I'm not interested" or "I don't qualify"), you should keep the `.innerText`:

```js
function() {
  var el = document.querySelectorAll('[aria-label="Close Modal"]')[0].innerText;
  return el;
}
```

This will return the text of the first button with `aria-label="Close Modal"`.

But if you want to return the `aria-label` value (i.e., "Close Modal"), you should change `.innerText` to `.getAttribute('aria-label')`:

```js
function() {
  var el = document.querySelectorAll('[aria-label="Close Modal"]')[0].getAttribute('aria-label');
  return el;
}
```

This will return "Close Modal".

Please ensure that the element is already loaded when this function runs. If the element isn't loaded yet, this code would return `undefined` because `document.querySelectorAll('[aria-label="Close Modal"]')[0]` would be `undefined`.

If you're trying to get the button text (i.e., "I'm not interested" or "I don't qualify") when a button click event occurs, you might want to use an Event Listener in GTM, listening for the `click` event on these buttons. Then, use `event.target.innerText` to access the text of the clicked button. This approach will help ensure the function runs in response to a button click, and that it correctly identifies the button that was clicked.